# Can't get title of the URL when loading too fast

Tags: javascript, protractor, mocha.js, chai

I am pretty new with mocha and I seem to love it so far. However I do get a small issue where it seems that it is trying to locate the pageTitle too fast and if I am lucky it actually manages to find the title but sometimes it doesnt and I am looking for a way something like "wait until the element is presented, if not after 10 sec then throw a error"

```
browser.get(url);


it('should have a title', (done) => {
    browser.driver
        .then(() => browser.getPageTitle())
        .then((text) => {
            assert.equal(text, "TEST", 'Not able to find the title');
        })
        .then(() => done());
});
```

Right now if I am lucky it manages to caught it but mostly it throws an error which is a empty reponse which I believe is that it doesn't get the title due to it is too fast. How can I make a function something like "Wait until the title is there, and if its not after 10 sec then error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `browser.wait` with an [expectedCondition](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains). Try this

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains('required_url'),
    10*1000,
    "Url did not contain 'required_url' within 10 seconds"
);
```

Comment: Hmm im not quite sure where I should paste your part into my code? :(

Comment: @Thrillofit86 This would go exactly wherever you want to wait to occur. So in your case it belongs directly after the `browser.get(url);`. This is an important piece of protractor functionality which you are likely to use often so I would advice [reading the api docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) on it when you get a chance.

Comment: Oh right! I get your point now. I tried to run abit with browser.wair before but it seemed to skip the waiting part before but I will try your code tommorow since I just left the university :) - however your seems to be what the urlcontains and not the title if I am incorrect?

Comment: @thrill you are correct. There is a separate expected condition for [urlIs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlIs) which you can use instead if it suits your purposes better. Waits can sometimes get skipped if you have a combination of the default control flow  and the `async/await` syntax in your test. If you are only getting started I would strongly recommend using `async/await` throughout your project as it will save much headaches in the long run

Comment: Alright will check further into it! Thanks alot for the tip. I might comment again tommorow! :)

Comment: I saw that you answered my previous question before so I might continue here. Basically I did now `browser.driver   .then(() => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(piPage.getEmailValue()), 10000))` where I used `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;` however the code should be pretty similar but the sleeping time is not working for me.

Comment: What does `.getEmailValue()` return? ExpectedCondtions expected an element as the parameter

Comment: `.getEmailValue()` returns element(by.id('email').getAttribute("value");

Comment: You will need only the element to work with the expected condition. So `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('email'))), 10000))` would likely work.

Comment: It worked! However I am not able to use .then - but that would be different issue. Basically I would like to do something like `.then(() => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('email'))), 10000, "timed out"))` - `then((isPresent) => {
                assert.equal(isPresent, true, 'Email failed entering.')
            })` but we dont have any isPresent() ?

Comment: I really can't stress enough how much easier this will be if you switch to `async/await` for managing your promises instead of `.then()`. Using await you would simply write [like this](https://imgur.com/a/53LK34i). I'm actually not certain if the await is required in front of the assert there but included it just in case. If you make the switch now, and properly research how to use it, you'll thank yourself later

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    browser.get(url);


    it('should have a title', (done) => {
        browser.driver
            .then(() => browser.getPageTitle())
            .then((text) => {
                assert.equal(text, "TEST", 'Not able to find the title');
            })
            .then(() => done());
    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Oh right, But basically this means that it waits 1000 milliseconds everytime before looking for the element if I am correct? Or does it retry to find the element until 1000 milliseconds is passed?

Answer (score 1):

Import chai and chai-as-promised

```
const chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
const expect = chai.expect;
```

Try using expect now

```
it('Check page title', () => { expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Protractor practice website - WebTables'); })
```

Now expect is of chai assertion library and not default jasmine.

Comment: I was thinking about Jasmine but I with my mates have decided to go with Chai and Mocha :(

Comment: Yes you can use expect oh chai also

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Oh alright but might I ask you whats the real difference between using .then vs. the way you are doing it? Because through the code it doesnt seems anywhere a sort of "wait until the title element is finished loading" or something like that. Wouldnt your code just throw a exception then?

Comment: Promise when getting resolved you can access the resolved value by using the then callback. But expect already can make use the resolved value for assertion.

Comment: How would your except work in that case because in my code I wrote at the beginning, the only faulty I know is that it is too fast to read the title which returns an empty string and to compare with yours, you either have a sort of "sleep/wait" function so I believe that would hit the exception immedently?